# SOC with more than 4Gb ram?

Tags: memory, raspberry-pi, energy-efficient

Are there any arm SOCs with large mounts of ram such as 16Gb ? Several phones have come out with 8Gb ram, so I expected the same developments to happen in the SOC sector. I believe there are ARM based data centre servers with high ram loads too. Why is this the case, is it due to the cost and the market these devices are aimed at?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Pine RockPro 64](https://www.pine64.org/devices/single-board-computers/rock64/) now exists with a 4Gb option, as does the Raspberry Pi 4